# Запрос к АПИ SpeechKIT не работает(401) — где ошибка?

Tags: javascript, fetch, text-to-speech, yandex-speechkit

запрос к **Яндекс. SpeechKIT** API через Браузер возвращает [ошибку авторизации 401](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/concepts/response):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя аналогичный код для NodeJS работает.
Не могу понять, в чём соль.

Документация Яндекса: [описание метода АПИ](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/tts/request)

Мой Код:

```js
let api_key = '***мой АПИ код*********';
let params = new URLSearchParams();
const text = 'Привет!';
params.append('text', text);
params.append('voice', 'jane');
params.append('emotion', 'good');
params.append('lang', 'ru-RU');
params.append('speed', '1.0');
params.append('format', 'oggopus');
//================ кнопочка запроса ===================================
const fetchButton = document.getElementById("fetchButton");

fetchButton.onclick = () => {
  alert('кнопка нажата');
  fetch('https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: params,
      mode: "no-cors", //иначе ругается
      headers: {
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Api-Key ' + api_key,
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(`responce is ${res}`);
      // return res.json();
      //const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat2.ogg');
      //res.body.pipe(dest);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`!!! + ${err} + !!!!!!!!`));
}
```

Comment: в документации написано `-H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAM_TOKEN}" `

Comment: Аналогичный но не тот же самый. Чтоб получить нужно авторизоваться в яндекс и получить токен

Comment: Токен временный, а  АПИ ключ постоянный, и я его получил, и с ним Ноде ЖС вполне работает.

Comment: так ваш вопрос всё ещё актуален?

Comment: @nörbörnën да, актуален, неделю уже никто решить не может

Comment: ok. выложите комментом свой IAM_TOKEN и FOLDER_ID, я посмотрю на запрос, а потом их удалите

Comment: @nörbörnën у меня нет токена, зато есть Api-Key рабочий валидный. И с ним FolderID не нужен. Здесь можно в личку написать?

Answer (score 0):

Поле mode со значением 'no-cors' позволяет использовать только ограниченный набор заголовков в запросе. А именно:

```
  Accept;
  Accept-Language;
  Content-Language;
  Content-Type (с некоторыми значениями).
```

Так как в запросе указано поле со значением 'no-cors', то браузер не добавляет заголовок Authorization. В результате чего вы  получаете ошибку со статусом 401.

Это можно легко проверить удалив строчку

```
mode: "no-cors", //иначе ругается
```

и воспользовавшись браузером, в котором будут отключены CORSы.

Более подробно эта проблема описана здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors